# Return LINQ expression result into named / strongly-typed variable

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

I need to pass the result of Linq function into strongly-typed variable of `ZipTwoBusinessObject` type, so other components using this object later can know what kind of data to expect.

In my case this component is `asp:Repeater` Web Form control where I need to pass in the type to have strongly typed repeater control, however this is more general issue.

I am using latest Visual Studio 2019.

```
Public Class ZipTwoBusinessObject
   Public Property Name As String
   Public Property Value1 As Decimal
   Public Property Value2 As Decimal
End Class

Dim ZipTwo As List(Of ZipTwoBusinessObject) = Test1.Zip(Test2,
                                                        Function(ccc, ddd) New With {
                                                          .Name = ccc.Name,
                                                          .Value1 = ccc.Value,
                                                          .Value2 = ddd.Value
                                                        }).ToList
```

The Linq expression returns error: BC30311  Value of type 'List(Of anonymous type: ...)' cannot be converted to 'List(Of ZipTwoBusinessObject)'.

UPDATE:

I might loop through anonymous elements of ZipTwo and assign it to the list of `ZipTwoBusinessObject`. But then it makes no sense to use Linq `Zip` method as I might zip those two objects in the same loop. However that would be a partial solution as not that easy with `Join` instead of `Zip`. And yes, I do use `Join` in the other place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wants `New ZipTwoBusinessObject With` instead of `New With`. The latter creates an anonymous type.

More info: [Anonymous Types (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/anonymous-types).